# Wrong render in view with Paginator handing 2 queries

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

im trying merge 2 queries, and after paginate that new variable:

```
$a = Message::where('conversation_id',$id)->where('user_id',$user->id)->where('s_1',1)
        ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->get();
    $b = Message::where('conversation_id',$id)->where('user_id',$conversation->recipients()->last()->user->id)->where('s_2',1)
        ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->get();
    $result = $a->merge($b);

    $messages = new Paginator($result, $result->count(), 1, 1);
```

work the foreach on the view, but the render is wrong and dont paginate, display all the results in only one page:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
            @foreach($messages as $i => $message)
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="{{$avatar[$message->user->username]}}" class="aoi pull-left"  />
                    <a href="{{route('profile',[$message->user->username])}}">{{ $message->user->name }}</a> 
                    {{ $message->body }}
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>
        {!! str_replace('/?', '?', $messages->render()) !!}
```

the messages var return the correct params, but dont work on view:

```
{"total":2,"per_page":2,"current_page":1,"last_page":1,"next_page_url":null,"prev_page_url":null,"from":1,"to":2,"data":
```

on the url: /message/1?page=2 display the 2 rows as well as in /message/1 and dont paginate.

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume that your Paginator here is actually LengthAwarePaginator since you're passing in the total number of items (or perhaps this is older version of Laravel).

The way you are constructing Paginator class:

```
$messages = new LengthAwarePaginator($result, $result->count(), 1, 1);
```

If you look at the Paginator class definition:

```
/**
 * Create a new paginator instance.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $items
 * @param  int  $total
 * @param  int  $perPage
 * @param  int|null  $currentPage
 * @param  array  $options (path, query, fragment, pageName)
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($items, $total, $perPage, $currentPage = null, array $options = [])
```

The fourth parameter is the current page, which you passed in as 1, causing it to always paginate it to the first page. You can simply pass in `null` (or just not avoid passing in fourth parameter), it will attempt to resolve current page automatically by checking current request parameter `page`.

In summary, change it to this:

```
$messages = new LengthAwarePaginator($result, $result->count(), 1);
```